# Re-applying for the same PhD program abroad after finishing it in one's home country?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, second-degree

This is a little bit hypothetical question… Let's assume I finished my PhD in math in my country but I am dissatisfied with it (assume I live in a developing country). Also I have enough money and time. Can I apply for a similar PhD program in an another country? Is it theoretically possible?

Comment: Welcome to this side. I edited the question slightly by correcting some grammar (I hope) and removing the salutation in the end. You may roll-back the edit if I somehow changed the intended meaning.

Comment: @Dirk Is the title right? He wants a overseas PhD? Or should it be "abroad"?

Comment: What is it you would hope to gain from the second program? Perhaps what you really want is a postdoc position.

Comment: Looking at all the answers, I see that the best route for me is to get a MSc. degree in my country (since I have to wait for one or maybe two years for personal reasons) and apply for a PhD degree abroad... Thank you all...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's generally not possible.  Almost all Ph.D. programs have a rule against admitting someone who already has a research doctorate.  Under special circumstances, one might be admitted as an unfunded Ph.D. student in a completely different field; but in the same field, never.

Comment: Thank you... Is it possible get a Master degree in math in home country and get a PhD in math aboard?. Is there any restriction?

Comment: Yes, that is actually very common.

Comment: One possible exception is if the PhD from the home country is of such poor quality that it is not recognized in the new country as a valid PhD.

Comment: @Bitwise:  Attending such a bogus institution would typically disqualify someone from admission to a Ph.D. program anyway.

Comment: Do you mean "...already has a research doctorate *in the same field*"? (As in, math after math, say). Because it is not very uncommon to see people with a Ph.D. in one field get another one in another (by field I mean discipline I guess, not an algebraist getting a degree in logic later)

Comment: @gnometorule: The university where I got my PhD has a general policy that students will not be admitted to a PhD program if they already have a PhD in *any* field.  Exceptions are possible but they require special permission.  See http://ucsd.edu/catalog/front/GradStud.html under "Duplication of Advanced Degrees".  As Buzz says, I think this is pretty common, though maybe not universal.

Comment: @Nate: Interesting. I studied with a Ph.D. in Physics (acquired prior to taking up Ph.D. studies at my school), and know several dual Ph.Ds., so it's new to me; thanks for pointing the possibility out. (None of those did math as a second degree; maybe that is a pattern)

Comment: This answer needs to indicate what country it is talking about. Otherwise, the claim that more than one research doctorate is ruled out in "almost all" programs except for "special circumstances" is probably not true across all legislations/research landscapes. For instance, in German-speaking places, it seems quite usual that very highly accomplished researchers have several (different, non-h.c.) doctoral degrees.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to obtain a PhD from a 1st world country I think your best bet is to go to another country as soon as possible. It will be a lot easier to get into a PhD program with a masters degree from a similar country, and it will be easier to continue your career abroad if you have followed a funded PhD program (as opposed to paying yourself / getting a grant from your home country).